# Couchdb: Access to two documents in a shows function

Tags: couchdb, show

I'm trying to create a show function which needs to access to two documents: The document in 'doc' reference and another document called 'users'

My function looks like:

```
function(doc,req){

var friends = doc.friends;
var listFriends = [];

for(int i = 0; i<friends.length; i++){
   var phone = friends[i].phone;
   if(users[phone] != "" ){
   listFriends.push(users[phone]);
   }
}
return JSON.stringify(listFriends);
}
```

I'm not an expert nor javascript neither couchdb. My question is, Is it possible to access to the second document (users) in a similar way like in the code? So far it returns a compilation error.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only access one document in a CouchDB show function. You could look at using a list function, which works on view results instead of documents.

Create a view where the two documents collate together (appear side-by-side in the view order) and you achieve an effect pretty close to what you wanted to achieve with the show function.

Comment: I'm trying to join both documents, where the 'phone' is the variable I need to pass. It doesn't seems possible in a view :S Can I get a clue about how to do it? Thanks a lot

Comment: This wiki page should explain the basics. http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation